# DomainTrustCheck and DomainJoinedCheck faied when creating VM for AVD

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, virtual-desktop

I'm trying to create a VM for a VM for our host pool. but it keeps getting
DomainTrustCheck faied
DomainJoinedCheck faied (This health check verifies that the session host is joined to a domain. If this check fails, it is fatal, and no connections will succeed. To solve this, join the virtual machine to a domain).
Sometime it works and sometime it does not work.

I searched everywhere and sometimes they said that its a known issue and had been fixed, but most of the time It did go anywhere.

[Azure error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlHhD.png)

Answer (score 0):

> Domain Join and Trust Issues in Azure VMs: A Step-by-Step Guide

According to the screenshot you've provided, the virtual machine (VM) you are trying to create has failed the domain join checks. The `DomainJoinedCheck` and `DomainTrustCheck` indicate that the VM is not correctly joined to the domain. This is a crucial step for a VM that belongs to a host pool, especially for services like Windows Virtual Desktop (WVD) or similar.

Here are some steps you can try to troubleshoot and resolve this issue:

1. **Network Settings and Connectivity**: Confirm that the VM's network settings allow it to communicate with the domain controller. This includes verifying Network Security Group (NSG) and firewall settings that may prevent the VM from accessing domain controllers​.
2. **DNS Configuration**: Ensure the VM is using a DNS server that can resolve domain names correctly, which is vital for domain connectivity.
3. **Check Secure Channel Health**: Use PowerShell to run `Test-ComputerSecureChannel` to check if the secure channel between the VM and the domain controller is healthy. If it's not, you may need to repair it with the same cmdlet followed by the `-Repair` switch.
4. **Reset Machine Password**: If the secure channel repair does not work, you might need to reset the machine password with the `Reset-ComputerMachinePassword` cmdlet using PowerShell, which often helps re-establish secure channel communication.
5. **Rejoin Domain**: As a last resort, if the above steps don't resolve the issue, you may need to remove the VM from the domain with the `Remove-Computer` cmdlet and rejoin it to the domain with the `Add-Computer` cmdlet using PowerShell.

Sometimes, these steps do not work because the problem is more complicated and depends on the environment or a specific configuration. In these situations, you need to collect detailed logs and get help from Microsoft or a network/domain expert.

**Reference:**

- Check with resolution provided by @[Glenn Horton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/users/na/?userid=8153f2f6-9396-462c-be3b-460cd64bc9dd)
  on the same [issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1471034/azure-virtual-desktop-domainjoinedcheck-failed)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshoot-broken-secure-channel

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I ran through the tutorial for a second time, having not deleted the registration in Intune. The new host failed to register, presumably because of a name conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Just do one thing. Change the user name and password or change the password or Create a session host with new user name and password.  Don't use the same username and password created with previous session host.